# Changing value of a search - Parent Child Structure

Tags: python, pandas, parent-child

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'id': [112, 114, 221, 262, 299, 300], 'parent_id': [300, 262, 558, 221, 560, 299], 'name': ['zona1', 'zona2', 'Activo1', 'zona3', 'Activo2', 'zona4']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

My goal is to create another column with the name of the parent_id that matchs with a list of 6 items:

```
list_names_act = [558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563]
```

So, I get the first item of the column id = 112. Since 112 is not found in list_names_act I have to get the item at the same position of the column parent_id = 300 and do the same comprobation. 300 is not in list_names_act so I must search it in column id and check if the item in the column parent_id (299) in the same position  is in list_names_act. 299 is not in list_names_act so I must get that item again and search it in id and, again, check if the item in parent_id is in list_names_act. In this last iteration, the value does belong to list_names_act  so I must get the value of the column name in that position and replicate that name to all the values that were needed to get there including the last one.
My output would be this:

```
    data = {'id': [112, 114, 221, 262, 299, 300], 
        'parent_id': [300, 262, 558, 221, 560, 299], 
        'name': ['zona1', 'zona2', 'Activo1', 'zona3', 'Activo2', 'zona4'],
       'name_activo': ['Activo2', 'Activo1', 'Activo1', 'Activo1', 'Activo2', 'Activo2' ]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I´ve tried with for loops but I´m only capable of filling 42 regs and I really don't know how to handle the change in the value that I'm looking for:

```
nom_activo_grande = []

for i in range(len(locacion_merge['id_x'])):
    if locacion_merge['id_x'][i] in lista_tipos:
        nom_activo_grande.append(locacion_merge['name'][i]) 
        
    elif locacion_merge['parent_id'][i] in lista_tipos:
        nom_activo_grande.append(locacion_merge['name'][i]) 
        
        
    elif locacion_merge['parent_id'][i] not in lista_tipos:
        for j in range(len(locacion_merge['id_x'])):
            if locacion_merge['parent_id'][i] == locacion_merge['id_x'][j]:

    
    else: nom_activo_grande.append(0)
```

thanks so much

Comment: can you  show us the final output , current;y what you show cases as output is exactly the same as your input df

Comment: Is not the same. It has another column which is the desired output

Answer (score 0):

One approach, IIUC:

```
# create a parent graph (actually is a tree, forest?)
parents = dict(zip(df["parent_id"], df["id"]))

# create a map of id to assets
names = {key: value for key, value in zip(df["parent_id"], df["name"]) if key in list_names_act}

unnamed = [c for c in df["id"] if c not in names]

while unnamed:
    for parent, child in parents.items():
        # if parent is in the mappings but not the child
        if parent in names and child not in names:
            names[child] = names[parent]  # set the same asset as the parent
            unnamed.remove(child)  # remove from unassigned

df["name_activo"] = df["id"].map(names)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id  parent_id     name name_activo
0  112        300    zona1     Activo2
1  114        262    zona2     Activo1
2  221        558  Activo1     Activo1
3  262        221    zona3     Activo1
4  299        560  Activo2     Activo2
5  300        299    zona4     Activo2
```

1. The main idea is to create a parent-child graph (`parents`) and do a sort of [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on the graph, each time you visit a node assign the name  of the parent to this new un-visited node.
2. Iterate until all nodes have been visited and the mapping `names` contains all id.
3. Then simply do a mapping of the column `df["id"]` using `names`.

**Note:** This assumes an `id` has one and only one `parent_id`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/):

Here is your graph:

[image: graph]

```
import networkx as nx

# create the graph from the DataFrame
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent_id', target='id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

S = set(list_names_act)

# get ancestor that is in "list_names_act"
# (arbitrary one if several, remove next/iter for all)
d = {n: next(iter(nx.ancestors(G, n)&S), None) for n in G.nodes}

# map ancestor
df['act_id'] = df['id'].map(d)
# map name
df['name_activo'] = df['act_id'].map(df.set_index('parent_id')['name'])
```

output:

```
    id  parent_id     name  act_id name_activo
0  112        300    zona1   560.0     Activo2
1  114        262    zona2   558.0     Activo1
2  221        558  Activo1   558.0     Activo1
3  262        221    zona3   558.0     Activo1
4  299        560  Activo2   560.0     Activo2
5  300        299    zona4   560.0     Activo2
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Unfortunally, as this was just a sample of the data, it works perfect, but when I use the whole dataset, I can´t map the values because there are duplicates and I can not delete them.  Do you know how can I work it around?

Comment: Yes, as hinted in the comments of the code, don't use `next/iter` but collect `nx.ancestors(G, n)&S`, then you'll have sets in the dictionary. After the first `map`, you can `explode` the set into as many rows as there are items in the set. Let me know if this is unclear and please update your example.